# Windows 10 update changes partition labels

Tags: windows, multi-boot, opensuse

I have recently booted my dual system SuSe 42.1/Windows 10, under Windows, in order to install and use iTunes. As usual, since I use Windows rarely, the system went through an upgrade, rebooted, and the Linux grub disappeared. Further, I had difficulties in booting from USB.

After tweaking for a while and using a new installation on a usb-stick of Suse 42.2, I was able to use `fdisk` to find out that the labels of `/swap`, `/home` and `/` on three different partitions have been changed to something like `WINDOWS RESERVED PARTITION` and UEFI is now windows ...

The data are still there if I mount the partitions using the usb-linux but the tools do not see the system anymore. I have looked on internet and there seems to be confusion between "upgrade", such as from windows 8 to 10, which I did one year ago without any problem, and "update" as in my case i.e. update of a windows 10 system already working. I didn't find any discussion on this issue. I do not know the cause: aggressive policy of Microsoft, installation of iTunes, a virus?

I will try to see if I can revert the labels back to their previous settings, in which case some help would be appreciated, but mainly the issue here is that the usual state of affairs of Windows coexisting quietly with Linux on a machine seems to be lost. Is it no longer possible to have Windows and Linux coexisting and not affecting each other?

Comment: Windows 10 updates are notorious for borking a dual boot system and wiping out Linux. This is the reason why, to my dismay, I had to go for a Linux VM guest on my Win10 machine rather than choosing a dual boot configuration that I knew could disappear at any moment. BTW, +1 for "I am considering the option of erasing the system completely and switch fully to Linux" which is surely the best solution if you don't need Windows.

Comment: Thanks, at least a clear statement, I am astonished an issue like this, which imply the possible (I have backups) loss of data and especially a lot of time by users is not discussed more in forums like this. The main problem is that updates are done without any warning which is likely legal but being that they make a mess should be possible to control somehow this behavior. This is why I am considering to wipe it out. I am currently trying to restore the situation if I can I will post the results.

Comment: They are not done without any warning. You're just not using the system on a regular basis, hence they're a surprise for you. Depending on the edition you have more or less influence on the timing of updates. What do you mean by label? The partition type? What do you mean UEFI is now Windows? Consider including the output of `fdisk` with some explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange and Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two [SE] accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select ‘‘I need to merge user profiles’’ to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/235811/franco and https://superuser.com/users/738373/franco.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, so far. After backing up, I started a new installation using a USB stick loaded with openSUSE 42.2.

I started the beginning and I left the partitions chosen by the software, not doing any change. I left for a meeting and I got the smoothest installation ever. The network was set correctly, software downloaded without any intervention on my side and I found coming back my system up waiting for me to log-in. Further all my settings on the user part are there.

The printout from `fdisk` is the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A1FA4776-F20C-4E88-9353-F97E31C4F3B0
Dispositivo     Start      Fine   Settori   Size Tipo
/dev/sda1        2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2      206848   2050047   1843200   900M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda3     2050048   2312191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     2312192 392095735 389783544 185,9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   392095744 393017343    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6   393017344 397238271   4220928     2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7   397238272 439185407  41947136    20G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8   439185408 934809599 495624192 236,3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda9   934809600 976773119  41963520    20G Windows recovery environment
```

Despite the labels, still there as set by the Microsoft update, `/dev/sda1` is now an EFI boot set up by Linux, was UEFI Windows before, `/dev/sda7` is `/`, `/dev/sda6` is swap and `/dev/sda8` is `/home`

The printout of `df -k` is the following:

```
File system    1K-blocchi     Usati Disponib. Uso% Montato su
devtmpfs          1950580         0   1950580   0% /dev
tmpfs             1964664     46292   1918372   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs             1964664      2344   1962320   1% /run
tmpfs             1964664         0   1964664   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /.snapshots
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /srv
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/cache
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/lib/machines
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/tmp
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/lib/pgsql
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /tmp
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/spool
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/lib/named
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/lib/mariadb
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /usr/local
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /opt
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/log
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/lib/mailman
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/lib/libvirt/images
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /boot/grub2/i386-pc
/dev/sda1           98304     41295     57009  43% /boot/efi
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/opt
/dev/sda7        20973568   5308908  15484596  26% /var/crash
/dev/sda8       243792168 223358848  19425688  92% /home
tmpfs              392936        16    392920   1% /run/user/1000
```

Quick and dirty, I badly need the machine working, and, for my present needs, it is. As soon as I have time I will try to do better. To my knowledge, mounting the partitions by hand, I got to know that `/dev/sda7` is Btrfs and `/dev/sda8` is ext4.

I hope this can be useful to others somehow.